# How to connect an Angular App with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm currently learning Angular and I have a question.
How are we supposed to use nodeJS as a backend for our project.

To launch a dev angular project, you need to `ng serve`
and to launch a server nodes, you need to `node app.js`.

So what are we supposed to do first ?
launch a nodeJS server and then ... what ?

or

`ng serve` the angular app and then... what ?

I'm sorry if my question sound stupid for some, but I'm really trying to understand how it works here.

Comment: You could use your Node server to also serve up the built Andular project. Or you could run them separately, and just have your Angular app make it's API requests the the Node.js endpoints.

Comment: Angular app and node app would be seperate entities in this case. If you want to use api endpoints from node app into your angular app, then you will need that node app running,

Answer (score 1):

Using angular with node js as backend is usually called MEAN stack.There is plenty of tutorials on youtube about MEAN stack. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1tRLveSyNz8) could be a good point for starting.